# SQL query to get result based on groups

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table as shown here in this screenshot:

[image]

How do I query the table to get an additional column containing static value eg. `change` and `no change` based on `GROUP` and `VALUE` columns?

In the above case, I need `no change` as value for `GROUP`=1 as both GROUP and VALUE are same, but `change` for GROUP=2 as values in VALUE column for GROUP 2 are different.

Comment: can you draw your expected output, Please? and if possible provide SQLFiddle link.

Comment: Your last paragraph is super confusing, please re-read and take another stab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query which should cover you use case:

```
SELECT t1.GROUP, t1.ROW_NUM, t1.VALUE, t2.CHANGE
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT GROUP,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT VALUE) = 1 THEN 'change'
        ELSE 'no change' END AS CHANGE
    FROM table
    GROUP BY GROUP
) t2
ON t1.GROUP = t2.GROUP
```

By the way, you might get syntax errors since you somehow managed to call your columns "GROUP" which is a reserved keyword in most flavors of SQL.

Comment: You can use square brackets `[]` to handle reserved keyword.

Comment: I do not want to group the records in the end result..just need to show `change` or `no change` for each row

Comment: @Rohaan I updated my query.  You can simply `JOIN` my original answer back to your table to get what you want.

Comment: Joining will depend on the data and would break if a value is repeated, for instance if the values of the last row is `2,4,2`, the value `2` would not be distinct for group `2` even though record 8's value of `1` is different.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32962120/183181) for how to compare rows in the same result window.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [GROUP],
    ROW_NUM,
    CASE 
       WHEN [GROUP]=1 AND CHANGE=VALUE  THEN 'no change'
       WHEN [GROUP]=2 AND CHANGE!=VALUE THEN 'change'
       ELSE '' 
    END AS VALUE
FROM table
GROUP BY [GROUP]
```

---

Your question is a little unclear, as I initially took it that you wanted to compare two fields.  But perhaps, you are trying to compare two records in a result set; the current record to a previous one and only want 'no change' when both the columns have not changed between records.

To compare records, you could use the window function, [`lag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx), which can access value from a prior row in the window.  See below for a description on that page:

> Applies To: SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016 Preview
>
> Accesses data from a previous row in the same result set without the use of a self-join in SQL Server 2016. LAG provides access to a row at a given physical offset that comes before the current row. Use this analytic function in a SELECT statement to compare values in the current row with values in a previous row.

```
SELECT [GROUP],
    ROW_NUM,
    VALUE,
    CASE 
       WHEN [GROUP] = LAG([GROUP],1,0) OVER(ORDER BY [GROUP],VALUE)
          THEN CASE 
             WHEN VALUE = LAG(VALUE,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY [GROUP],VALUE) 
             THEN 'no change'
             ELSE 'change'
          END
       ELSE ''
    END AS CHANGE
FROM table
ORDER BY [GROUP], ROW_NUM
```